# Printing elements of list, which is the value of HashMap

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have created a `HashMap<String,String[]>`

I am trying to print the key alongside the elements of the list at each value.

So for instance the first line should print

```
English : Alex Lamplough Kayleigh Lamplough Bella Lamplough
```

My code:

```
public class Students {

private HashMap <String, String[]> subjects;

public Students() {
    
    subjects = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    
}

public void initialDetails() {
    
    this.subjects.put("English", new String[] {"Alex Lamplough", "Kayleigh Lamplough", "Bella Lamplough"});
    this.subjects.put("Maths", new String[] {"Bill Burr", "Kayleigh Lamplough", "Jake Stanford"});
    this.subjects.put("Science", new String[] {"Paul Hatton", "Jake Stanford", "Bill Burr"});
    this.subjects.put("IT", new String[] {"Jake Stanford", "Alex Lamplough", "Julie King"});
    this.subjects.put("Sports", new String[] {"Barbara Kensington", "Bella Lamplough", "Alex Lamplough"});
    this.subjects.put("Languages", new String[] {"Julie King", "Harry Milner", "Bella Lamplough"});
    this.subjects.put("History", new String[] {"Harry Milner", "Kayleigh Lamplough", "Bill Burr"});
    
    Set set = this.subjects.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(mentry.getKey() + " : " + mentry.getValue());
    }
    

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a better approach would be if we can use for loop when we get the Key value after that we go  the for the HashMap values that are an array of String

```
String [] names = (String[]) entry.getValue();
```

And of course we go with a for each to print the elements

```
    for(Map.Entry entry : subjects.entrySet()){
            System.out.print("key " + entry.getKey() + " : ");
            String [] names = (String[]) entry.getValue();
            for(String name : names){
                System.out.print(name + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
key English : Alex Lamplough Kayleigh Lamplough Bella Lamplough 
key Maths : Bill Burr Kayleigh Lamplough Jake Stanford 
key Science : Paul Hatton Jake Stanford Bill Burr 
key Languages : Julie King Harry Milner Bella Lamplough 
key IT : Jake Stanford Alex Lamplough Julie King 
key History : Harry Milner Kayleigh Lamplough Bill Burr 
key Sports : Barbara Kensington Bella Lamplough Alex Lamplough
```

Full code

```
    public class Students {

    private HashMap<String, String[]> subjects;

    public Students() {

        subjects = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Students s = new Students();

        s.initialDetails();
    }

    public void initialDetails() {

        this.subjects.put("English", new String[]{"Alex Lamplough", "Kayleigh Lamplough", "Bella Lamplough"});
        this.subjects.put("Maths", new String[]{"Bill Burr", "Kayleigh Lamplough", "Jake Stanford"});
        this.subjects.put("Science", new String[]{"Paul Hatton", "Jake Stanford", "Bill Burr"});
        this.subjects.put("IT", new String[]{"Jake Stanford", "Alex Lamplough", "Julie King"});
        this.subjects.put("Sports", new String[]{"Barbara Kensington", "Bella Lamplough", "Alex Lamplough"});
        this.subjects.put("Languages", new String[]{"Julie King", "Harry Milner", "Bella Lamplough"});
        this.subjects.put("History", new String[]{"Harry Milner", "Kayleigh Lamplough", "Bill Burr"});

//        Set set = this.subjects.entrySet();
//        Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
//        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
//            Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
//            System.out.println(mentry.getKey() + " : " + mentry.getValue());
//        }


        for(Map.Entry entry : subjects.entrySet()){
            System.out.print("key " + entry.getKey() + " : ");
            String [] names = (String[]) entry.getValue();
            for(String name : names){
                System.out.print(name + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks! Does just the trick.

Comment: Keep Learning :)